# Plotting a function output against given input

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If a certain amount of money (called the principal P) is invested in a bank account, earning an interest rate i compounded annually, the total amount of money T<sub>n</sub> that will be in the  account after n years is given by:

**T<sub>n</sub> = P(1+i)<sup>n</sup>**

So I had written a function that will receive input arguments for P, i, and n, and will return the total amount of money T<sub>n</sub>.

```
function T=calculate(P,i,n)
    T = P*((1+i)^n);
end
```

Now I want to write a script that calls this function to plot T<sub>n</sub> after 20 years as a function of interest rate, with interest rate ranging from 0 to 10% in increments of 0.1%. But I am not getting how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use element-wise operations, you can do this calling the function only once with `i` a vector. For element-wise operations, you have to use the dot operator`.`. Include it in your function to properly use vectors as inputs:

```
function T=calculate(P,i,n)
    T = P.*((1+i).^n); % you don't need the first dot for this particular example
end
```

Define your values and calculate the results:

```
P=1;
n=20;
i=0:1e-3:1e-1;
T=calculate(P,i,n);
```

Plot the results

```
plot(i,T);
```